# WPF CheckedListBox SelectionMode="Multiple" not updating SelectedIndex on SelectionChanged Event

Tags: c#, wpf, checkedlistbox

I  am testing Kelly Elias' article on [Creating a WPF checkListBox](http://www.jarloo.com/how-to-create-a-checkedlistbox-in-wpf/). I'm needing to get the selectedIndex and the checkedbox text. Everything works as needed until I change the listbox's SelectionMode to "Multiple" which I need implemented. After that, the SelectedIndex nor the SelectedItem does not change using the SelectionChanged event. These two properties only show info of the first checkedbox. However, all of the checkedboxes are added to the SelectedItems collection. Can someone please assist with this issue?

Thank you in advance!!!

```
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace Jarloo
{
    public class Customer : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private string _name;
        public string Name
        {
            get { return _name; }
            set
            {
                _name = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("Name");
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    public class CheckedListItem<T> : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        private bool isChecked;
        private T item;

        public CheckedListItem()
        {
        }

        public CheckedListItem(T item, bool isChecked = false)
        {
            this.item = item;
            this.isChecked = isChecked;
        }

        public T Item
        {
            get { return item; }
            set 
            {
                item = value; if (PropertyChanged != null) PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Item"));
            }
        }

        public bool IsChecked
        {
            get { return isChecked; }
            set
            {
                isChecked = value; if (PropertyChanged != null) PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("IsChecked"));
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public ObservableCollection<CheckedListItem<Customer>> Customers { get; set; }

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Customers = new ObservableCollection<CheckedListItem<Customer>>();

            Customers.Add(new CheckedListItem<Customer>(new Customer() { Name = "Kelly Smith" }));
            Customers.Add(new CheckedListItem<Customer>(new Customer() { Name = "Joe Brown" }));
            Customers.Add(new CheckedListItem<Customer>(new Customer() { Name = "Herb Dean" }));
            Customers.Add(new CheckedListItem<Customer>(new Customer() { Name = "John Paul" }));

            DataContext = this;
        }

        private void ListBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            int index = listbox1.SelectedIndex;
            string testName = ((CheckedListItem<Customer>)listbox1.SelectedValue).Item.Name;
        }
    }
}


<Window x:Class="Jarloo.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen">
    <Grid>
        <ListBox Name="listbox1" ItemsSource="{Binding Customers}" SelectionChanged="ListBox_SelectionChanged"
                 SelectionMode="Multiple">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ListBoxItem}}, Path=IsSelected}"
                              Content="{Binding Path=Item.Name}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Given that the SelectedIndex is the first in Multiple I suspect that is just how it works.  Since you have a valid SelectedItems collection try and go down that path.

Comment: I could do the below but I still need the SelectedIndex to change accordingly:

string test = ((CheckedListItem<Customer>)listbox1.SelectedItems[listbox1.SelectedItems.Count - 1]).Item.Name;

Even the CurrentItem property is not working correctly. It's stuck on the first Item in the listbox

string currentItem = ((CheckedListItem<Customer>)listbox1.Items.CurrentItem).Item.Name;

Comment: Need and get are not the same.  If it is not firing it is not firing.

Comment: I'm not sure what you getting at here. I'm needing assistance on getting the SelectedIndex to change using the "Multiple" SelectionMode.

Comment: If  SelectedIndex is not changing with Multiple SelectionMode there is not likely much you can do about it.  That is just how the control works.  Look outside the box for other ways to get there.

Answer (score 0):

The way the control works when `SelectionMode` is `Multiple` (or `Extended`), is to set the `SelectedIndex` *only* when the first item is selected (I.E. added to `SelectedItems`). Additional items get added to the end of the `SelectedItems` list, but `SelectedIndex` remains unchanged.

To trick this behavior into the desired results, we will take the newly added item(s) off the end of `SelectedItems` and essentially insert it(them) back into the front. But for this to work, we have to do more than just make the newest item the first item in `SelectedItems`. We have to empty the list and re-add each entry so that the default behavior now recognizes the desired item as the `SelectedValue` and will update the `SelectedIndex`. So we'll use a temporary list to help.

Additionally, we'll add a flag to indicate if we are currently busy correcting the `SelectedItems` order. This is needed since we will be modifying the list and `ListBox.SelectionChanged` will be recursively called.

```
private bool busy;

private void ListBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
  if (!this.busy)
  {
    this.busy = true;

    /*
     * If items were added to the end of the list,
     * reverse the list appropriately.
     * Removed items are self-handling.
     */
    if (e.AddedItems.Count > 0)
    {
      List<CheckedListItem<Customer>>  reversed = new List<CheckedListItem<Customer>>();

      // Reverse newly added items.
      foreach (var item in e.AddedItems)
      {
        listbox1.SelectedItems.Remove(item);
        reversed.Insert(0, (CheckedListItem<Customer>)item);
      }

      // Maintain previously reversed items' orders.
      foreach (var item in listbox1.SelectedItems)
      {
        reversed.Add((CheckedListItem<Customer>)item);
      }

      // Clear and reset selections to trigger SelectedIndex change.
      listbox1.UnselectAll();

      foreach (var item in reversed)
      {
        listbox1.SelectedItems.Add(item);
      }
    }

    int index = listbox1.SelectedIndex;
    string testName = listbox1.SelectedValue == null ? string.Empty : ((CheckedListItem<Customer>)listbox1.SelectedValue).Item.Name;
    System.Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", index, testName);

    this.busy = false;
  }
}
```

---

Sidenote: Instead of the `busy` flag and condition check, you could instead do the following:

```
private void ListBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
  listbox1.SelectionChanged -= this.ListBox_SelectionChanged;

  // Same code within the condition...

  listbox1.SelectionChanged += this.ListBox_SelectionChanged;
}
```

It will achieve the same purpose of preventing a recursive call and subsequent stack overflow. I just don't know whether unsubscribing and subscribing the event handler is less or more expensive than the boolean check (my guess is *more* but researching, there seems to be no preference, as shown in [these](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2692705/3773066) [three](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/95403e75-d742-48f6-b62c-ece440215cf2/textchanged-recursion) [results](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5012854/3773066)).